# Problems with downloading and installing Nix on ubuntu

Tags: installation, nix

I've installed ubuntu and now I'd like to install NIX in order to later install ARTIQ enviroment. However once I'm following steps from manual https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/installation/installing-binary
I'm having problem with installing the NIX.

When I'm using following command:

sudo curl -L https://nixos.org/nix/install | sh

The response is following:

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100  4052  100  4052    0     0  20375      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 20375
downloading Nix 2.18.1 binary tarball for x86_64-linux from 'https://releases.nixos.org/nix/nix-2.18.1/nix-2.18.1-x86_64-linux.tar.xz' to '/tmp/nix-binary-tarball-unpack.dm63s9mZs1'...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0Warning: Failed to open the file 
Warning: /tmp/nix-binary-tarball-unpack.dm63s9mZs1/nix-2.18.1-x86_64-linux.tar.
Warning: xz: No such file or directory
  0 20.6M    0 16375    0     0   143k      0  0:02:26 --:--:--  0:02:26  142k
curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination
sh: failed to download 'https://releases.nixos.org/nix/nix-2.18.1/nix-2.18.1-x86_64-linux.tar.xz'
```

So, clearly, there is a problem with downloading the file(archive).
I've downloaded this archive and unpacked it manually. However I have no udea how sould i proceed next. What next should I try to do in order to install NIX? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4wEe.png)

Comment: Writing code with Nix-the-language is definitely on-topic here. _Installation_, probably not (as installing Nix is not a task unique to software development); you'd likely do better at https://discourse.nixos.org/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't have `xz` installed.  Try running this:

```
sudo apt install xz-utils
```

Comment: Thank you for your response however after applying your command the return in the terminal is stil exactly the same

Comment: The problem isn't lack of `xz-utils`, as that's already installed on a default Ubuntu desktop. The problem appears when the second curl execution fails to download.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've managed to install *nix* just by manually downloading and unpacking the archive. Then in the terminal I went into that unpacked archive and just run the command `./install`
In the attached image there is a screenshot of a terminal
[image: Shell output]

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt install nix-setup-systemd
```

Ubuntu already has a package for Nix. Just install the package instead of using the generic nix installer.